# Why does exception catching a method call chain with a function wrapper seem to be much more expensive than manual checks?

Tags: java, functional-programming, nullpointerexception

I was playing with the idea of using a function wrapper like below for any method call chains that might have a null value returned at some point:

```
public static <T, R extends Class> R getOrPassNullable(Function<T, R> call, T param) {
try {
  return call.apply(param);
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
  return null;
}
}
```

I came up with a simple benchmark to test out the performance impact: create a dummy variable with some fields nested 2-3 calls deep, and measure runtimes using my function wrapper vs plain old manual checks.

For the benchmark itself, I slightly modified an answer from some other post to simply execute a given method a number of times as specified:

```
public class TimeTracedExecutor<T, R> {
    Function<T, R> methodToExecute;
    public TimeTracedExecutor(Function<T, R> methodToExecute) {
      this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
    }
    public void executeWithInput(String taskDescription, T t, int times) {
      Instant start = Instant.now();
      for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        methodToExecute.apply(t);
      }
      Instant finish = Instant.now();
      String format = "Task took %s milliseconds: " + taskDescription;
      String elapsedTime = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()
          .format(Duration.between(start, finish).toMillis());
      System.out.println(String.format(format, elapsedTime));
    }
}
```

Then for the test case, I used a simple class definition with nesting fields like this:

```
public class NestingDoll {
  private NestingDoll nested;
    
  public NestingDoll getNested(){
    return this.nested;   
  }
  
  public void setNested(NestingDoll val){
    this.nested = val;
  }
}
```

For implementations to test, I used these two methods:

```
  private NestingDoll getNestedFunctionalBypass(NestingDoll root) {
    return getOrPassNullable(() -> root.getNested().getNested().getNested().getNested());
  }

  private NestingDoll getNestedManualChecks(NestingDoll root) {
    if (root != null
        && root.getNested() != null
        && root.getNested().getNested() != null
        && root.getNested().getNested().getNested() != null)
      ) {
      return root.getNested().getNested().getNested().getNested();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Finally, I set up and ran my benchmark like this:

```
public void profileNullChecks() {
    NestingDoll root = new NestingDoll();
    NestingDoll depth1 = new NestingDoll();
    NestingDoll depth2 = new NestingDoll();
    NestingDoll depth3 = new NestingDoll();
    depth2.setNested(depth3);
    depth1.setNested(depth2);
    root.setNested(depth1);

    TimeTracedExecutor<NestingDoll, NestingDoll> nullChecks =
        new TimeTracedExecutor<NestingDoll,NestingDoll>(
            this::getNestedManualChecks);
    TimeTracedExecutor<NestingDoll, NestingDoll> functionalBypass =
        new TimeTracedExecutor<NestingDoll,NestingDoll>(
            this::getNestedFunctionalBypass);
    nullChecks.executeWithInput("Manual null checks", root, (int) Math.pow(10, 10));
    functionalBypass.executeWithInput("Functional bypass", root, (int) Math.pow(10, 10));
  }
```

I was expecting maybe some performance impact but it turned out to be huge: 9ms with manual checks vs ~7000 with my function wrapper.

[image: snapshot from user console]

I am not sure why the difference is in multiple orders of magnitude here. Is there something I am missing with how I set this up or the way I implemented the wrapper, or is there something about functional interfaces that makes them so slow to use?

Comment: Exceptions are expensive in general, null checking is extremely efficient, and benchmarking is hard and likely to mislead you if you don't use a heavily tested benchmarking tool.

Comment: First part might be a big factor here but I disagree on the second part. I am not testing some complex api or trying to get accurate metrics, just trying to roughly compare execution times of two simple methods.

Comment: You are combining way too many things.  If you want to isolation test, perform like for like with only 1 variable.  Consider getDepositManualChecks is a single method invocation, whereas getDepositFunctionalBypass contains lambda so slows down there too due to instantiation of the annonymous functional class.  Rather, give them like for like environment by providing a new getOrPassNullable which performs the null check on call and param.

Comment: @VictorS, trying to roughly compare execution times of simple methods is _really hard on the JVM_ and genuinely needs a fancy benchmarking framework.  To give at least a little idea of why, Java only optimizes code as it gets used more often, so there's often a massive bias towards saying the first thing that gets measured takes longer than the second thing that gets measured.  Even for extremely simple things being benchmarked, measuring performance on Java is _hard._

Comment: Louis, that's not hard.  Just loop through each method 20k times first to force JIT to compile before measuring, and then another x times for the actual measurement.  The problem here is that it's not isolation testing so OP will have no idea which of the various factors is causing the slowdown.

Comment: Regardless of the reason for the time difference, catching NullPointerException is an extremely bad idea and a bad design.  NullPointerException exists to indicate programmer mistakes.  You are assuming that it will only happen for one particular reason, which implies you are assuming that neither you nor any other developer who will ever maintain your code will make a mistake.

Comment: @VGR Just to clarify this is not meant to represent a general use case. I simply want to extract fields from deep nested POJOs without a null check every step so there is not really a room for mistake -- the field is either populated or not

Comment: A get-method is a method, not a variable.  The point of using methods, and not variables, is that sometimes classes need to evolve;  it’s possible (and often desirable) for a get-method do more than just blindly return a private field.  So there can very well be code in those methods that is capable of throwing unintended NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: @VGR again, I am not trying to go into a general case hyperbole reciting bits from Bloch. This is use-case specific for when I can safely assume my data objects come as a bunch of nested POJOs and I want to avoid having 4/5 lines of my methods being null checks